# MVC Form with PartialViewResult on submit, doesn't post the data in the PartialViewResult

Tags: model-view-controller, submit

I am learning mvc and jquery. Requirmeent => There are "Categroies". Each categories can have a list of "Tasks".  User should be able to resort the "Tasks" as he wishes by drag-drop and save to the db.

The form that I am working on contains the following

1. A list of Categories displayed in a  element. When the user selects a list item
   an ajax request is made to get the list of "Tasks"
2. A list of Tasks displayed in a  list.
3. A button to save the changes

I am able to implement all of the functionality including displaying categories, getting tasks and resorting. But the Save part is not working. When the form posts, I don't see the data for the Tasks in the FormCollection.

Here is the html.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Settings", "Settings", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formSettings" }))
{
<div style="width: 100%; background-color: Aqua; vertical-align: top">
    <div style="width: 50%; text-align: right; vertical-align: top; float: left; display: block;
        height: 300px;">
        <select id="listSettings"  name="listSettings" style="width:200px;height:280px;text-align:left;" size="@Model.Categories.Count()"  data-tasks="@Url.Action("GetTasks", "Settings", new { })">
            @foreach (string category in @Model.Categories)
            {
                <option title="category"  value="@category">@category</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="taskListId" style="display: block; width: 30%; float: left; height: 300px;">
        This will be replaced
    </div>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" title="Save" value="Save" />
</div>
}
```

The `<div id="taskListId".../>` above will be replace by ajax call to the server. Here is the partialviewresult html

```
<div id="taskListId" style="display: block; width: 30%; float: left; height: 300px;">
    <ul id="sortable" style="height: 280px;">
        @foreach (string s in Model)
        {
            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>@s</li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

When the form is submitted, why is it the FormCollection contain just 1 key "listSettings", but not the "sortable"?

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks,
Ravi.

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way to do that. Actually form post will not have `<ul>` data in it.  `<ul>` doesn't have a name attribute attached to it. so I wont find in form post data.

I solved the issue by using jquery to find the `<ul>` and `<li>` items and attaching them as name value pair to the form post data. Then I posted the data using ajax.